# ajax json string returning undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, space-tree

I am using a library of thejit.org, and the graph is space tree.

```
st.onClick(node.id, {
   Move: {
   enable: true,
   offsetX: 30,
   offsetY: 5
   },
   onComplete: function() {
    $.ajax({

     type: "POST",
    url: "Home",
    data: "node="+node.id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

st.loadJSON(data.d); //error
st.compute();
st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
st.onClick(st.root);
st.refresh();
}
```

I am trying to regenerate the graph with a new json once a node is
clicked. In the onclick function I am making an ajax call, the data if
printed out is correct. even if iI use the data printed to decalre a
varialbe and use it. graphs is generated,but when I use it with ajax I
get undefined.

## Edit-1

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String data=    
"{id:\"90\",name:\"s\",data:{},children:[{ id:\"2\",name:\"2\",data:{},children:[{ id:\"3\",name:\"3\",data:{},children:[]},{ id:\"1265\",name:\"1265\",data:{},children:[]}]},{ id:\"8\",name:\"8\",data:{},children:[{ id:\"9\",name:\"9\",data:{},children:[]},{ id:\"12\",name:\"12\",data:{},children:[]}]}]};";

obj.put("d", data);

out.print(obj);

out.flush();
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` too see if anything is being returned.

Comment: yes..its printing the string correctly.

Comment: `console.log(typeof data)`, maybe it's not being parsed into JSON correctly.

Comment: Also, when you did `console.log(data)`, there was a `d` property, right?

Comment: yes, I did and its the same string I wanted. The thing is, when i am copy pasted the string in the call, it worked perfectly but when I try to access it directly its giving problem.

Comment: ok when i tried typeof data its giving be object, not json. is this a problem? and when i do it for data.d it is coming as string.

Comment: `typeof data` should be `object`, that's correct, and `string` for `typeof data.d` is also (obviously) correct.  This is a weird problem.

Comment: I am also editing my question, which shows the generation of json string in the servlet file.

Comment: Maybe you need to do `st.loadJSON($.parseJSON(data.d));`?